# Knex.js transaction generates valid SQL (without errors) but update is not reflecting in the DB

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

Using PostgreSQL with Knex I'm iterating through an object representing the rows to be updated within a transaction. Using the Knex debugger shows the execution of each transaction with no errors. However, there are no changes to the table in the DB.

When I dump the raw SQL that Knex builds and execute it on my DB it does exactly what I'd expect. The rows are updated.

The code:

```
const updatedLocations = knex.transaction((trx) => {
      locations.forEach(async (location) => {
        location.entry_id = entry.id;
        await trx("locations").update(location).where("id", location.id);
      });
    });
```

I'm out  of ideas here and the debugger is not helping.

Answer (score 0):

missing the first `await` at `knex.transaction(...`

Comment: I tried including await at knex.transaction, but the behavior is unchanged. It still generates valid queries but does not make a change to the DB. No errors in the debugger. Just nothing.

Comment: looking at the [documentation](https://knexjs.org/guide/transactions.html#transactions) you need to return the transaction from within `return await trx("locations...`